Improve logo to an ERC-20 Token in Safe Wallet
I am looking for some guidance to update the quality of the logo we showcase on SAFE. I previously shared a logo but it was pixelated, this one below will have a clean look. Is it possible to upgrade the logo?

proof of legitimacy: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/autonolas
Network: Ethereum mainnet
Contract: https://etherscan.io/token/0x0001a500a6b18995b03f44bb040a5ffc28e45cb0
Logo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14R5SYQGXph-g1l2E8p7U0nabtCEY0jYQ/view


Thanks for reaching out! Unfortunately the logo used by Safe is automatically fetched from Coingecko; the one we are using is the one they are using.
Maybe you can try contacting them to try to upgrade the logo quality?
Let me know; Best, Louis
